# MVC 2 UpdateModel - how does it work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I ask because I cannot get this code to work. 
I get an exception; 
"The model of type 'ITOC.WebUI.Models.Contract' could not be updated."
Which does not seem very helpful.

** EDIT **
The above exception has been resolved because of a spelling mistake in the prefix, a classic "Magic String". Now the problem is that NOTHING GETS UPDATED!
** END EDIT **

I have to admit I am not clear how UpdateModel works, and I am not clear how the prefix works.
The viewmodel is specified in the webpage;

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ITOC.WebUI.Models.ContractViewModel>" %>
```

and the ViewModelClass is

```
public class ContractViewModel
{
    //private ITOCEntities db = new ITOCEntities();
    public Contract contract { get; set; }
    public IList<ContractType> contractTypes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> contractTypesSelectList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.contractTypes.Select(item => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = item.ContractType1,
                Value = item.ContractTypeId.ToString()
            });
        }
    }


    public Contact clientContact { get; set; }
    public Contact contractAdministratorContact { get; set; }

    public ContractViewModel()
    {
        using (var db = new ITOCEntities())
        {
            this.contractTypes = db.ContractTypes.ToList();

            this.clientContact = new Contact();
            this.contractAdministratorContact = new Contact();
            this.clientContact.ContactTypeId =
                db.ContactTypes.Where(x => x.ContactType1 == "Client").SingleOrDefault().ContactTypeId;
            this.contractAdministratorContact.ContactTypeId =
                db.ContactTypes.Where(x => x.ContactType1 == "CA").SingleOrDefault().ContactTypeId;
        }
    }
    public ContractViewModel(int contractId)
    {
        using (var db = new ITOCEntities())
        {
            this.contractTypes = db.ContractTypes.ToList();
            this.contract = db.Contracts.Where(x => x.ContractId == contractId).SingleOrDefault();
            this.clientContact = 
                db.Contacts.Where(x => x.ContactId == this.contract.ClientContactId).SingleOrDefault();
            this.contractAdministratorContact =
                db.Contacts.Where(x => x.ContactId == this.contract.ContractAdministratorContactId).SingleOrDefault(); 

        }
    }
}
```

---

The Controller is;

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Inputter")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int contractId, FormCollection formValues)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var db = new ITOCEntities())
        {
            var contract = db.Contracts.Single(x => x.ContractId == contractId);
            string letter = contract.ContractNo_Letter;

            UpdateModel(contract, "Contracts");

            var clientContact = db.Contacts.Single(x => x.ContactId == contract.ClientContactId);
            UpdateModel(clientContact, "Contact");
            var contractAdministrationContact = 
                db.Contacts.Single(x => x.ContactId == contract.ContractAdministratorContactId);
            UpdateModel(contractAdministrationContact, "Contact");
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Yes, see comment under your name.

Comment: I am thinking the problem is the name of the prefix. The name of the class is "Contract", but that throws an exception, as does "contract". "Contracts" doesn't throw an exception, but is not updated either.

Answer (score 3):

try using `TryUpdateModel` in an if/ else statement

```
if (TryUpdateModel(contract))
{
    // save changes
}
else
{
    // handle
}
```

`TryUpdateModel` and `UpdateModel` are intended to be used to *merge* an object with a posted model object.

> Updates the specified model instance
>   using values from the controller's
>   current value provider.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel.aspx

Try reading [this post](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2008/09/08/ASPNETMVCUpdateModelTryUpdateModelDataBinding.aspx) about these two methods.

---

try changing your Post Action Method to match your Model Object

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Inputter")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ContractViewModel model)
{
    //
}
```

if the id's on your form match to the properties of your `ContractViewModel` object then `model` will post with those values

Comment: Yes, when I do that one of the object properties returns a null exception. does this show what the problem is, that I have to populate every field with a required field validator, even though that field is not in the form?

Comment: If you have a hidden input on the form with the ID you're using you can load that object based on that ID. Then call UpdateModel(myloadedobject) and it will merge items on the submitted page and ignore properties that aren't.

Comment: I have made the fields HiddenFor on my form. However in the Controller ModelView, I still get a null exception for one of these fields

Answer (score 1):

To see what failed look at your Controller.ModelState entries.  That will tell you what failed to bind.  In my experience its usually a datatype mismatch.

---

1 and 3 of CubanX's answer don't really have any impact on ModelBinding errors.  2 can be ignored because if your getting a bind error you know its probably binding and probably don't have to worry about the Prefix.

Comment: The Controller.ModelState only contains the ContractId. Is this the problem do you think?

Answer (score 0):

A few things I noticed right off:

1. You don't have a ViewModel specified in your view.  This line here means a View with no type specific model:

   `<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>`
2. Without seeing the view, we can't be sure what you're trying to bind to here, or even if you should be using a prefix.
3. You're not actually passing in the FormValues collection into UpdateModel.  Try:`UpdateModel(contract, "Contract", formValues)`

Comment: There is something funny about the markup. I tried to edit it, but in the edit view the markup is correct!
So what you need to see is this;
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ITOC.WebUI.Models.ContractViewModel>" %>

Comment: Did you try passing the formValues to UpdateModel?  Also, can you post the View code?

Comment: I tried passing on the formValues. The formValues are correct, but they do not seem to update the class.

Comment: I think at this point we really need to see the View code to be able to help further, can you add that to the question?